# Windows Socks Service

Tags: windows, networking, socks

Using Windows, is there a way to connect to other computers and use their network/internet to dial out? How can I do this?

Is it necessary to do router/modem forwarding configuration for it to work?

Comment: What exactly is "that system"?

Comment: Edited for better clarity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they're called Proxy servers.

If you're looking specifically for "SOCKS Servers", [here's a list to get you started](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS_Servers).

As for port forwarding, whether you'll need it or not and how it should be configured depends on what you're trying to accomplish and how you're using SOCKS.

For something to help you connect to the Internet through another Windows machine, check out Windows' in-built [Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/using-ics-internet-connection-sharing).